# Update state of a immutable component from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am developing for a use case where I need to slightly change a pre existing component. This is the code for the preexisting component, but I can not change the ABC.tsx file, can just import it.

```
export const ABC: React.FC<IABC> = (props) => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState('0');
  return ();
};
```

Now, the use case is from the calling component I want to change the selectedKey state of ABC to a different value say '1'. Is there a way to do so in react? I can use the ABC to create clones/wrapper components but not sure how to proceed with modifying states of ABC. Any leads would really help.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to tamper with the ABC.tsx file, maybe do something like this

```
export const ABC: React.FC<IABC> = (props) => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState(props.abc_integer);
  return ();
};
```

**Otherwise** there is **no** other way to do it, even if you run a clone or do some React children on, you will still need to tamper. get whoever is on your team that wrote component ABC to change it to suit what you want or you simple clone its code and run it through a wrapper.

psa: As far as I know, any other method is anti-react pattern

Comment: Yeah, was thinking the same but cannot change the file. Thanks :)